# Help needed fitting a general latent variable model in glmmTMB

Tags: mixed-model, latent-variable, glmmtmb

as Ben Bolker suggested [here](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/984#issuecomment-1919593623) I should ask this question in this forum!
I am trying to fit a GLVM similar to the one presented in this vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/covstruct.html#reduced-rank as I was suggested to do this by a statistician.

The data I have is area under the curve following spectrometry analysis of toad toxin secretions. 15 different compounds have been identified in the secretions of toads and I would like to find out if there are differences in the composition (i.e., more of a specific toad toxin) in the secretions of toads from specific locations (4 different locations). I have formatted my data set into long format.

```
    > head(toxins)
># A tibble: 6 × 6
>  Toad_ID Location  Sex    log10SVL Toxin  Area
>  <chr>   <chr>     <chr>     <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
>1 CU195   Cape_Town female     1.93 TT7    494.
>2 CU195   Cape_Town female     1.93 TT8    192.
>3 CU195   Cape_Town female     1.93 TT9   1100.
>4 CU195   Cape_Town female     1.93 TT10   544.
>5 CU195   Cape_Town female     1.93 TT12   305.
>6 CU195   Cape_Town female     1.93 TT14  1167.
> str(toxins)
>tibble [600 × 6] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
> $ Toad_ID : chr [1:600] "CU195" "CU195" "CU195" "CU195" ...
> $ Location: chr [1:600] "Cape_Town" "Cape_Town" "Cape_Town" "Cape_Town" ...
> $ Sex     : chr [1:600] "female" "female" "female" "female" ...
> $ log10SVL: num [1:600] 1.93 1.93 1.93 1.93 1.93 ...
> $ Toxin   : chr [1:600] "TT7" "TT8" "TT9" "TT10" ...
> $ Area    : num [1:600] 494 192 1100 544 305 ...
```

So far, I've been log(y+1) transforming my y variable to fit a glmm with gaussian family:

```
fit_g1a <- glmmTMB(log(Area+1) ~ Location * Sex + 
               rr(Location |Toxin, d = 2) + rr(Toxin|Toad_ID, d = 2),
             data = toxins)
```

I'm especially interested in the `Location | Toxin` term to see if specific toxins occur in higher amounts in toads of specific locations.
After some model selection based on AIC, I decided on this model:

```
fit_g2c <- glmmTMB(log(Area + 1) ~ Location + Sex + 
                 rr(Location | Toxin, d = 4) + rr(Toxin | Toad_ID, d = 2),
               data = toxins)
```

The fixed effect of `Location` is controlling for general differences in the area under the curve between locations (it seems that toads from the first location have generally more toxin than from the other locations, and therefore the area under the curve from the spectrometry is generally higher for toads from this location. The `Sex` fixed effect checks for general differences between the sexes. The random intercept of `Toad_ID` controls for inter-dependence and the random slope for `Toxin` accounts for the correlations among Toxins. Lastly, I have the `Location | Toxin` random effect, which is supposed to tell me which toxins occur more prominently in which locations. Using `anova()`, I determined that a model with the `Location | Toxin` term provides a significantly better fit than a model without the term. However, when I want to see which specific toxins are more prominent in which locations using
`ranef(fit_g2c)` and `plot_model(fit_g2c, type = "re", show.values = TRUE)`, I see that the estimates for my fourth location are very small:

```
$Toxin
     (Intercept) LocationMauritius LocationReunion LocationCape_Town
TT10  -0.9671358         0.6877188      1.47336824      1.205429e-06
TT12  -0.4091168         0.4425725     -1.32286924      5.852014e-06
TT14  -0.7891181        -0.7838166      1.01857989     -1.541306e-07
TT16   0.4410460        -0.4826110     -0.50307829     -2.788336e-06
TT18  -0.2660568        -1.1611358     -0.03094444     -3.073159e-06
TT19   1.1873699        -0.2000598     -0.46025354     -2.741581e-07
TT20   1.1835372         0.2719932      0.40175692     -7.958919e-08
TT22   1.8972002         0.5311096      0.79150775      2.277659e-06
TT23  -0.8726360        -0.8476109     -1.73618011      3.216233e-06
TT24  -0.1601007        -2.2621117      0.73948689     -4.943835e-06
TT25   0.5144228         0.2036495     -0.69332780     -1.714787e-06
TT26   1.1307610         0.8049135      0.37142541     -2.392636e-06
TT7   -0.8814806         0.4381274     -0.43754205      6.684454e-07
TT8   -1.8193548         1.2714524      0.65175510     -1.639845e-06
TT9   -0.1890797         1.0857231     -0.26372446      3.840653e-06
```

I find this suspicious as it would suggest that all toxins are evenly distributed in this location, which is certainly not the case from looking at the raw data (some toxins make up to 42 % of the entire toxin composition). I have tried using different values for "d" but it did not change the result.
What could cause this issue? Should I be using a different model formula?

To comment on Ben Bolker's post in the original thread: I've used `Location |Toxin` and not `Toxin |Location` as with the second option, I would get a warning message:

```
> diagnose(fit_g3c)
```

"Unusually large Z-statistics (|x|>5):

```
    d~(Intercept) theta_Toxin|Toad_ID.1 theta_Toxin|Toad_ID.2 
       -24.546926              6.437753              5.589324
```

Large Z-statistics (estimate/std err) suggest a *possible* failure of the
Wald approximation - often also associated with parameters that are at or
near the edge of their range (e.g., random-effects standard deviations
approaching 0).  (Alternately, they may simply represent very
well-estimated parameters; intercepts of non-centered models may fall in
this category.) While the Wald p-values and standard errors listed in
summary() may be unreliable, profile confidence intervals (see
?confint.glmmTMB) and likelihood ratio test p-values derived by comparing
models (e.g. ?drop1) are probably still OK.  (Note that the LRT is
conservative when the null value is on the boundary, e.g., a variance or
zero-inflation value of 0 (Self and Liang 1987; Stram and Lee 1994; Goldman
and Whelan 2000); in simple cases, these p-values are approximately twice as large as they should be.)"